# append to list function encodes german umlauts wrong

Tags: python, python-3.x, subprocess

I want to iterate through some files within a folder and send the path of the files to a list. Then I want to pass this list to a subprocess to execute a bash command:

```
procfiles = []
os.chdir("/path/to/directory")

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for file in files:
        if '.mp3' in file:
            filename = os.path.join(root, file)
            print(filename)
            procfiles.append(filename)
print(procfiles)

args = [command, with, arguments].extend(procfiles)
process = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=False)
output, error = process.communicate()
```

But I get the following output when the file contains a german umlauts letter. For example: ä, ö or ü

```
./titleWith ä or ü - artist with ü.mp3                                         #print(filename)
['./titleWith \udcc3\udca4 or \udcc3\udcbc - artist with \udcc3\udcbc.mp3']    #print(procfiles)
```

This means that there is something wrong with the encoding during the
`procfiles.append(filename)` process, right?

After that the subprocess fails with the error:

> UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udcc3' in
>   position 43: surrogates not allowed

Infos:

- Python 3.5.3
- OS: Debian Jessie
- Kernel: 4.9.58+
- architecture: armhf

**UPDATE:**

I just noticed that when I am executing it manually with the user *root* or *www-data* it works, but when I execute it via my *custom php script* (its only a `shell_exec('/usr/bin/python3 /path/to/script.py >> /path/to/log.log 2>&1')`) it doesn't work.

Shouldn't that be the same as when I execute it from the user www-data manually? Or do I have some other environment variables set when the python script is executed from a php script?

Answer (score 0):

This is exactly expected behavior, although in your case the file system encoding is wrong so it outputs surrogate escapes to correctly re-encode your string.
The backslash escapes are just the exact representation of the string.
If you wanted to correctly print the characters (although this depends on the encoding of your `sys.stdout` and of your terminal) then call `print()` on every string. Seems like subprocess doesn't pass `errors=surrogateescape` to `str.encode()`.

Answer (score 0):

If I run this script:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os
import subprocess

procfiles = []
os.chdir("/home/dede/tmp/")

for root, dirs, files in os.walk('.'):
    for file in files:
        if '.mp3' in file:
            filename = os.path.join(root, file)
            print(filename)
            procfiles.append(filename)
print(procfiles)

args=["ls", "-la"]
args.extend(procfiles)
process = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=False)
output, error = process.communicate()
```

I get this output:

```
dede@i5:~> python3 tst.py 
./Leere Datei.mp3
./Kopie ä  von Leere Datei.mp3
['./Leere Datei.mp3', './Kopie ä  von Leere Datei.mp3']
-rw-r--r-- 1 dede users 6 31. Mär 16:50 ./Kopie ä  von Leere Datei.mp3
-rw-r--r-- 1 dede users 6 31. Mär 16:50 ./Leere Datei.mp3
```

So the *wrong* part must be somewhere else in your code....

...or your mp3's have their *Umlaute* in Windows-Encoding.

Comment: I just noticed that when I am executing it manually with the user root or www-data it works, but when I execute it via my custom php script (its only a `shell_exec('/usr/bin/python3 /path/to/script.py >> /path/to/log.log 2>&1')`) it doesn't work. Shouldn't that be the same as when I execute it from the user www-data manually? Or do I have some other environment variables set when the python script is executed from a php script?

Answer (score 0):

**Python3.5**

Convert your strings first:

```
procfiles = [s.encode('utf-8', errors='surrogateescape').decode('utf-8')
             for s in procfiles]
```

**Python 3.6**

You can specify with `errors='surrogateescape'` that this error is ignored:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(args, shell=False, errors='surrogateescape')
```

Comment: with `errors='surrogateescape'` I get the error:
`TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'errors'`
I guess you meant that argument from decode or encode as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21116263/7987318).

Do I have to de or encode it with that before I pass it to the subprocess?

Comment: Ups. I used Python 3.6, which has this keyword argument. Python 3.5 doesn't have it.

Comment: Updated my answer.